# Using awk create two arrays from two column values, find difference and sum differences, and output data

Tags: bash, csv, awk, bioinformatics

I have a file with the following fields (and an example value to the right):

```
hg18.ensGene.bin 0
hg18.ensGene.name ENST00000371026
hg18.ensGene.chrom chr1
hg18.ensGene.strand -
hg18.ensGene.txStart 67051161
hg18.ensGene.txEnd 67163158
hg18.ensGene.exonStarts 67051161,67060631,67065090,67066082,67071855,67072261,67073896,67075980,67078739,67085754,67100417,67109640,67113051,67129424,67131499,67143471,67162932,
hg18.ensGene.exonEnds 67052451,67060788,67065317,67066181,67071977,67072419,67074048,67076067,67078942,67085949,67100573,67109780,67113208,67129537,67131684,67143646,67163158,
hg18.ensGene.name2 ENSG00000152763
hg18.ensGene.exonFrames 0,2,0,0,1,2,0,0,1,1,1,2,1,2,0,2,0,
```

This is a shortened version of the file:

```
0 ENST00000371026 chr1 - 67051161 67163158 67051161,67060631,67065090,67066082,67071855,67072261,67073896,67075980,67078739,67085754,67100417,67109640,67113051,67129424,67131499,67143471,67162932, 67052451,67060788,67065317,67066181,67071977,67072419,67074048,67076067,67078942,67085949,67100573,67109780,67113208,67129537,67131684,67143646,67163158, ENSG00000152763 0,2,0,0,1,2,0,0,1,1,1,2,1,2,0,2,0, uc009waw.1,uc009wax.1,uc001dcx.1,
0 ENST00000371023 chr1 - 67075869 67163055 67075869,67078739,67085754,67100417,67109640,67113051,67129424,67131499,67143471,67162932, 67076067,67078942,67085949,67100573,67109780,67113208,67129537,67131684,67143646,67163055, ENSG00000152763 0,1,1,1,2,1,2,0,2,0, uc001dcy.1
0 ENST00000395250 chr1 - 67075991 67163158 67075991,67076022,67078739,67085754,67100417,67109640,67113051,67129424,67131499,67143471,67162932, 67076018,67076067,67078942,67085949,67100573,67109780,67113208,67129537,67131684,67143646,67163158, ENSG00000152763 0,0,1,1,1,2,0,-1,-1,-1,-1, n/a
```

I need to sum the difference of the exon starts and ends for example:

```
hg18.ensGene.exonStarts    67051161,67060631,67065090,67066082,67071855,67072261,67073896,67075980,67078739,67085754,67100417,67109640,67113051,67129424,67131499,67143471,67162932,
hg18.ensGene.exonEnds    67052451,67060788,67065317,67066181,67071977,67072419,67074048,67076067,67078942,67085949,67100573,67109780,67113208,67129537,67131684,67143646,67163158,
```

difference:

```
1290,157,227,99,122,158,152,87,203,195,156,140,157,113,185,175,226
```

sum (hg18.ensGene.exonLenSum):

```
3842
```

And I would like the output to have the following fields:

```
hg18.ensGene.name
hg18.ensGene.name2
hg18.ensGene.exonLenSum
```

such as this:

```
ENST00000371026 ENST00000371023 3842
```

I would like to do this with one awk script for all lines in the input file.  How can I do this?  This is useful for calculating exon lengths, say for a RPMK (Reads Per Kilobase exon Model per million mapped reads) calculation.

Comment: Start with `grep`. For example: `grep "exonStarts\|exonEnds" filename.txt`

Comment: FYI: http://biostar.stackexchange.com/ is another nice place to ask this kind of question :-)

Comment: @Dave Jarivs thank you for the comment, but I think I confused you with the wording of the question, the file is not actually laid out in a way that grep could be used to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
so ross$ awk -f gene.awk gene.dat
ENST00000371026 ENSG00000152763 3842
ENST00000371023 ENSG00000152763 1645
ENST00000395250 ENSG00000152763 1622
so ross$ cat gene.awk
/./ {
  name = $2
  name2 = $9
  s = $7
  e = $8
  sc = split(s, sa, ",")
  ec = split(e, ea, ",")
  if (sc != ec) {
    print "starts != ends ", name, name2, sc, ec
  }
  diffsum = 0
  for(i = 1; i <= sc; ++i) {
    diffsum += ea[i] - sa[i]
  }
  print name, name2, diffsum
}
```

Answer (score 2):

using the UCSC mysql anonymous server:

```
mysql -N -h  genome-mysql.cse.ucsc.edu -A -u genome -D hg18 -e 'select name,name2,exonStarts,exonEnds from ensGene' |\
awk -F '    ' '{n=split($3,a1,"[,]"); split($4,a2,"[,]"); size=0; for(i=1;i<=n;++i) {size+=int(a2[i]-a1[i]);} printf("%s\t%s\t%d\n",$1,$2,size); }'
```

result:

```
ENST00000404059 ENSG00000219789 632
ENST00000326632 ENSG00000146556 1583
ENST00000408384 ENSG00000221311 138
ENST00000409575 ENSG00000222003 1187
ENST00000409981 ENSG00000222027 1187
ENST00000359752 ENSG00000197490 126
ENST00000379479 ENSG00000205292 873
ENST00000326183 ENSG00000177693 918
ENST00000407826 ENSG00000219467 2820
ENST00000405199 ENSG00000220902 1231
(...)
```